# Dedicated graphics and onboard graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

I have a HP 430 notebook PC.
According to the specs, it probably has an integrated HD graphics card and a dedicated AMD graphics card, but when I go to my device manager, display adapters, only the integrated graphics card shows up. I guess that I don't have the drivers installed for it. So I went to HP support center, and downloaded the drivers, but after installing them, still no success.

So now, I am doubtful if my laptop even has a dedicated card or not (although [the link here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02822281-2%257CdocLocale%253Den_US%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) shows that it must have an dedicated one). So is there any way to check whether I surely have the dedicated card or not, and if yes, where and how to activate its drivers?

Comment: Your questions is a bit confusing.  You say "...only the integrated graphics card shows up. I guess that I don't have the drivers installed for it."  then you say "So now, I am doubtful if my laptop even has a dedicated card or not  (although the link here shows that it must have an dedicated one)"  What tells you that an integrated graphics controller is listed in the device manager?

Comment: The link does not show that it must have a dedicated graphics adapter;  It shows it has the option to have one.  Do you know what chipset you have; that might narrow down your options.  Should be listed in the device manager as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to open the laptop up and look,  But by the look of it I doubt you have a dedicated graphics card as its rare for windows not to see hardware unless its switched off in the bios.

if you bought it recently expecting it to have one I would contact HP, and ask them if the model you bought came with one, then if it doesn't ask if you can exchange/refund.

Answer (score 0):

If you run DXDIAG and look at the Display tab you will see information about your GPU.

1. Press Start
2. Run
3. Type DXDIAG and press enter
4. Click Yes
5. Go to the Display tab and post results here

~WinglessWinter

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact variant; the 430 is not one model but a series. In particular, variants with the "Mobile Intel GM45 chipset" do *not* have a "Radeon HD 6370M Graphics card".